# Different app version when beginning debug versus restarting already running app

Tags: flutter, dart

I noticed when I first begin debugging a flutter app I'm developing I will get an old version of the app that I previously loaded. When I then restart the app without closing it out I will have the correct version.

Is there a cache that is not being cleared prior to when I begin debugging? Flutter clean works but I have to perform this manually every time. Possibly a setting in visual studio.